# Get environment variables from a docker image in a Jenkins job

Tags: docker, jenkins

I have declare an env variable in my Dockerfile :

```
ENV GRADLE_VERSION="4.4"
```

When I dump environment in my Jenkins job I see her :

```
GRADLE_VERSION=4.4
```

But I can't get her :

```
echo "GRADLE VERSION -> ${env.GRADLE_VERSION}" / GRADLE_VERSION is null
```

Do you know why ?

Comment: pipeline or traditional execution shell? Show how you dump and more exact code how you see it null

Comment: Strange, I tested in a pipeline and  echo "GRADLE VERSION ->  ${env.GRADLE_VERSION}" worked for me

Comment: It's a pipeline and I use sharedlib. It's very strange but if I can dump her that means variable is passed to container. But I can't recovery her.. If I found a solution I will share the solution

Comment: I solved the problem. My problem was that i was trying to access a variable that was a system variable... 


To recover it I had to do this : 

`def GRADLE_VERSION = sh(script: "echo \${${GRADLE_VERSION}}").toString()`